# Should we encourage users to upvote clarification questions asked in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-votes

If there are too many comments, then comments with lower votes are hidden and comments with higher votes are presented, You must click on the "show more comments" to see all the comments. The issue that rises with this is when, say, I asked something in the comments and then another user replied.

Usually what happens on SO is that the response gets 10X upvoted while the original comment itself gets 1X upvoted. It makes it slightly difficult to follow. You're like "this was an answer to what?!"

I am fully aware that you can expand the comment sections but still just wondering what's the best approach? Just upvote the response or upvote both the 'question asked in the comments' and its response?

Comment: _"Comments are sorted based on the most voted comment."_: False. They're sorted by date.

Comment: Comments may be partially *hidden* if their number is large enough. Vote comments help select which ones remain visible. Just click the 'show more comments' link and all comments are displayed. Comments are always shown in date order.

Comment: Comments get deleted over time.. That's why you add the important things to the answer.  I am not really getting your point here

Comment: _"Comments get deleted over time"_ Not automatically, @suraj.

Comment: _"<...>, then they are sorted based on the most voted comment."_ Still not right. They're _sorted_ by date. They may be _hidden_ based on votes.

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought it's obvious what I meant. Initially they aren't sorted by date—if there are too many comments, rather they are sorted by highest vote. If you click on the **show more comments** then you will see them all sorted by date

Comment: @Honey, "Sorted" isn't the same as "Shown"/"Hidden"

Comment: True..but the point is comments are secondary in SO IIRC .   The relevant info need to be in q and  a..

Comment: @suraj: True, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not sure if anyone has yet addressed the question. I meant what you said. Made several edits to clarify that. So my question is **should users also upvote the question?** It's a simple yes or no.

Comment: @Honey: "Should"? No. If they want to, they can.

Comment: @Honey: and all this makes it that users should just vote when they feel like voting on a comment. No encouragements needed.

Comment: I've never considered it as a problem but even if it is, it shouldn't be solved by forcing users to upvote the things they don't want to. If a comment is upvoted therefore visible, you can show the comment that it answered as well.

Comment: A more useful thing to do would be to flag obsolete comments. If a thread on the main site has gotten that long it likely still has comments that have already been incorporated into the post or otherwise no longer apply.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure why the question is marked as unclear nor why my answer which is a copy/paste of your comment is downvoted. I sometimes feel like an absolute newbie when it comes to understanding the community.

Comment: I think it got marked as Unclear because you ask about up voting the question and it's not clear that you mean a question posed in the comments section and not the question post itself.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

According to Martijn:

> users should just vote when they feel like voting on a comment. No
>   encouragements needed.